# Scala jackson deserialize

Tags: json, scala, jackson

I want to deserialize json with jackson in scala

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper
import com.fasterxml.jackson.module.scala.DefaultScalaModule
import com.fasterxml.jackson.module.scala.experimental.ScalaObjectMapper
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.DeserializationFeature;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.annotation.JsonDeserialize; 
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonProperty;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonCreator; 



case class Metadata(@JsonProperty("hive_type_string") hive_type_string: String)

case class Field(@JsonProperty("name") name: String, @JsonProperty("type") typeField: String, @JsonProperty("nullable") nullable: Boolean, @JsonProperty("metadata") metadata: Metadata) 

case class StructTable(@JsonProperty("type") typeField: String, @JsonProperty("fields") fields: Seq[Field])


val mapper = new ObjectMapper() with ScalaObjectMapper
mapper.registerModule(DefaultScalaModule)
val struct = mapper.readValue[StructTable](json_struct)
```

json_struct :

{
"type":"struct",
"fields":[
{
"name":"code_role",
"type":"string",
"nullable":true,
"metadata":{
"HIVE_TYPE_STRING":"string"
}
},
{
"name":"libelle_role",
"type":"string",
"nullable":true,
"metadata":{
"HIVE_TYPE_STRING":"string"
}
}
]
}

This is the error : **com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.InvalidDefinitionException: Cannot construct instance of `StructTable`: non-static inner classes like this can only by instantiated using default, no-argument constructor**

Can someone help me ?

Thanks.

Comment: You need to post the actual code that fails rather than just snippets, and try to pare it down to the simplest version that shows the problem.

Comment: Do you really need to use a runtime-reflection based **Java** library. Instead dog any of the many **Scala** libraries which derive the decoders at compile time being safer and faster?

Comment: @Tim It is the actual code, the error is related to the last line : val struct = mapper.readValue[StructTable](json_struct)

Comment: Do you have something simple to use @LuisMiguelMejíaSuárez ?

Comment: A couple of options: [**circe**](https://circe.github.io/circe/), [**uJson**](http://www.lihaoyi.com/upickle/#uJson), [**jsonitter-scala**](https://github.com/plokhotnyuk/jsoniter-scala), etc.

Comment: @Arthhur10 It is not valid Scala code; you can't have bare `val` declarations like that at the top level. I suspect that this is nested in `class` somehow which is causing the error. You also don't say how `json_struct` is defined.

Comment: @Tim I use this code on Apache Zeppelin.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can pick another library like [jsoniter-scala](https://github.com/plokhotnyuk/jsoniter-scala) then add to your dependencies:

```
libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
  // Use the %%% operator instead of %% for Scala.js  
  "com.github.plokhotnyuk.jsoniter-scala" %% "jsoniter-scala-core"   % "2.6.2",
  // Use the "provided" scope instead when the "compile-internal" scope is not supported in your build tool
  "com.github.plokhotnyuk.jsoniter-scala" %% "jsoniter-scala-macros" % "2.6.2" % "compile-internal"
)
```

Here is a code snippet to parse your input and print parsed data:

```
import com.github.plokhotnyuk.jsoniter_scala.macros._
import com.github.plokhotnyuk.jsoniter_scala.core._

case class Metadata(@named("HIVE_TYPE_STRING") hive_type_string: String)

case class Field(name: String, @named("type") typeField: String, nullable: Boolean, metadata: Metadata)

case class StructTable(@named("type") typeField: String, fields: Seq[Field])

implicit val codec: JsonValueCodec[StructTable] = JsonCodecMaker.make

val json_struct = """{ "type":"struct", "fields":[ { "name":"code_role", "type":"string", "nullable":true, "metadata":{ "HIVE_TYPE_STRING":"string" } }, { "name":"libelle_role", "type":"string", "nullable":true, "metadata":{ "HIVE_TYPE_STRING":"string" } } ] }""";
val struct = readFromString(json_struct)

println(struct)
```

The expected output is:

```
StructTable(struct,List(Field(code_role,string,true,Metadata(string)), Field(libelle_role,string,true,Metadata(string))))
```

Also you can run it online with Scastie [here](https://scastie.scala-lang.org/0ApqnLEtQoSBWAbsLa16yw).

Comment: Thanks, will have a look.